# Generated source files should not be edited in php storm

Tags: laravel, phpstorm-2016.3

I am editing `min.css` file in php storm 2016.3 but its showing a message,

> Generated source files should not be edited. the changes will be lost

And not saving what I add.

Comment: Not user of phpstorm, but happy to help out. Could you post the file path and a screenshot with the message?

Comment: Just don't edit anything inside the public directory. Edit the files inside the resources/assets folder

Comment: @dacastro4 how to edit inside resources/assets as there are variables.scss and app .scss files not that minified css file where i want to edit?

Comment: @MrMK3 Check the gulp/webpack file (depending on your Laravel version) and you can see what's the name of the file after compiling the assets.

Answer (score 5):

Laravel generated this file through MIX, so that file is a file that was generated by compiling the SCSS files on your project.

What Phpstorm is trying to tell you is that if you make changes in that file, and then run something like "npm run watch" its going to get overwritten by the SCSS compiler.

Comment: 100%, accept this answer was going to reply the same exact thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error if the IDE expects a file to be a Blade file (for example if it created in a subdirectory of `views/base_templates`) but it is not named as such.

In this case, the solution is to ensure the name of the file ends in `.blade.php`.